# How to access a protected znode from ZooKeeper using zkCli?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have created a znode using:

```
zookeeper-0:/opt/zookeeper/bin # ./zkCli.sh create /mynode content digest:user:pass:cdrwa
```

How to access the znode using the zkCli.sh utility now?

```
zookeeper-0:/opt/zookeeper/bin # ./zkCli.sh get /mynode
Connecting to localhost:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
Authentication is not valid : /mynode
zookeeper-0:/opt/zookeeper/bin #
```

The getAcl is showing the following:

```
zookeeper-0:/opt/zookeeper/bin # ./zkCli.sh getAcl /mynode
Connecting to localhost:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
'digest,'user:pass
: cdrwa
zookeeper-0:/opt/zookeeper/bin #
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create the digest ACL using the hashed password.

[**ZooKeeper Programmer's Guide**](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.13/zookeeperProgrammers.html)

> **digest** uses a username:password string to generate MD5 hash which is then used as an ACL ID identity. Authentication is done by sending the username:password in clear text. When used in the ACL the expression will be the username:base64 encoded SHA1 password digest.

### Generate the hashed password

```
$ java -cp "./zookeeper-3.4.13.jar:./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar" \
org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestAuthenticationProvider user:pass
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
user:pass->user:smGaoVKd/cQkjm7b88GyorAUz20=
```

### Create a node using the hashed password

```
[zk: zookeeper(CONNECTED) 0] create /mynode content digest:user:smGaoVKd/cQkjm7b88GyorAUz20=:cdrwa
Created /mynode
```

### Accessing the protected node

```
[zk: zookeeper(CONNECTED) 1] get /mynode
Authentication is not valid : /mynode
[zk: zookeeper(CONNECTED) 2] addauth digest user:pass
[zk: zookeeper(CONNECTED) 3] get /mynode
content
cZxid = 0x14
ctime = Wed Sep 12 19:37:48 GMT 2018
mZxid = 0x14
mtime = Wed Sep 12 19:37:48 GMT 2018
pZxid = 0x14
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 7
numChildren = 0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer

But, still I am still having an issue, It is working fine when I am using a single session. For example, 

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] addauth digest user:pass
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] get /mynode
content


is working fine, But, when I try to get it as follows --

zookeeper-0:/opt/zookeeper/bin # ./zkCli.sh addauth digest user:pass
Connecting to localhost:2181
zookeeper-0:/opt/zookeeper/bin # ./zkCli.sh get /mynode
:Authentication is not valid : /mynode
zookeeper-0:/opt/zookeeper/bin #

Comment: @dgm that's because you need to auth for each session, if you want to pass it one step you could put your commands in a file and then redirect that `zkCli.sh <commands` or pipe them in with a one liner `printf "addauth digest user:pass\nget /mynode | zkCli.sh"`, although it is generally not a good idea to store a password in a file or include it as a parameter in a command

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the content of the zkcli.sh script, you will see a commented out block showing how to configure an environment variable with credentials:

```
#SOLR_ZK_CREDS_AND_ACLS="-DzkACLProvider=org.apache.solr.common.cloud.VMParamsAllAndReadonlyDigestZkACLProvider \
#  -DzkCredentialsProvider=org.apache.solr.common.cloud.VMParamsSingleSetCredentialsDigestZkCredentialsProvider \
#  -DzkDigestUsername=admin-user -DzkDigestPassword=CHANGEME-ADMIN-PASSWORD \
#  -DzkDigestReadonlyUsername=readonly-user -DzkDigestReadonlyPassword=CHANGEME-READONLY-PASSWORD"
```

You can configure the environment variable SOLR_ZK_CREDS_AND_ACLS on your local system with the correct credentials following this template and then the zkcli.sh script will use them when communicating with ZooKeeper.